# PartialViewResult on submit return another partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I have

```
public PartialViewResult CodePartial(string code){
     ...
     return PartialView("anotherpartial");
}
```

which on has submit button and I want that on post executed ***anotherpartial*** partialviewresult. but instead it returns this partial view inside of ***CodePartial*** view. And on debugging it's not going inside of ***anotherpartial*** action. 
How can I improve that?

***CodePartial.cshtml***

```
@model Kubeti.Models.Codes



@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CodePartial", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.code)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.code)

  <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}

<div id="result" style="width: 500px; height:500px; border:1px solid red;">
```

***index.cshtml***

```
@Html.Partial("CodePartial")
@Html.Partial("anotherpartial")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your method:

```
public PartialViewResult CodePartial(string code){
     ...
     return PartialView("anotherpartial");
}
```

doesn't return 'to an action' as such. It simply returns the `PartialView` representation (meaning without the view being rendered with the layout, amongst other things) of the view that you specify.

If you want to return to another action, you need to post to that action or, alternatively, [do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228533/is-there-a-way-to-return-an-actionresult-from-controller-b-called-from-controlle).